# Python: Parent Class not recognizing __init__ of its subclasses

Tags: python, inheritance

I have been working with inheritance, but I got confused as to why my parent class is not recognizing the **init** of my sub classes. Here is an example of my code that is giving me none when run, when it shouldn't.

```
class Coins(object):
    def make_change(self, amount):
        change = []
        for coin in (self._coins):
            change.append(amount // coin)
            amount = amount - change[-1] * coin 
class US_Coins(Coins):
    def __init__(self):
        self._coins = [50, 25, 10, 5, 1]
class Metric_Coins(Coins):
    def __init__(self):
        self._coins = [50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
metric = Metric_Coins()
us = US_Coins()
print(us.make_change(73))
print(metric.make_change(73))
coins = Coins()
print(coins.make_change(27))
```

Comment: Inheritance works upwards, not downwards. Meaning `Metric_Coins` will inherit properties from `Coins`. But `Coins` won't inherit anything from anyone. Meaning `Coins` won't get any values or properties from any of the other classes. One such variable is `self._coins` which is only created in two of the classes, but never defined in `Coins`. As @antona pointed out correctly. [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/python/images/multiple-inheritance-in-python1.png) shows a basic concept of how this works.

Comment: You should add a `return change` to your `make_change`method so that it gives you an output. Also, only subclasses can get methods from their parents and not the other way around.

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is? A parent class is *not meant to* do anything with methods of its subclasses. Even in your case, it would not make sense if `Coins` were to use `__init__` of its subclasses - the two are not compatible. Would `Coins()._coins` be `[50, 25, 10, 5, 1]` or `[50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `self._coins` field in `Coins` class. Without it, function `make_change` cannot be executed because it evokes field that does not exist in this parent class (`for coin in (self._coins)`).

Edited: in order to achieve your goal you need to create a field inside `Coins` class:

```
class Coins(object):

    def __init__self():
        self._coins = []

    def make_change(self, amount):
        change = []
        for coin in (self._coins):
            change.append(amount // coin)
            amount = amount - change[-1] * coin 


class US_Coins(Coins):

    def __init__(self):
        self._coins = [50, 25, 10, 5, 1]


class Metric_Coins(Coins):

    def __init__(self):
        self._coins = [50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]


metric = Metric_Coins()
us = US_Coins()
print(us.make_change(73))
print(metric.make_change(73))
coins = Coins()
print(coins.make_change(27))
```

Now you are able to operate with `make_change` method on the us and metric; and also on coins object.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to account for the changing self._coins ([50, 25, 10, 5, 1] and [50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]) in the Coins class?